# upgrade weblogic to 12.2.1.3.0 and java from 1.7 to 1.8 - exception WELD-001408 unsatisfied dependencies

Tags: java, weblogic12c, jboss-weld

I upgraded weblogic to version 12.2.1.3.0 (Before was 12.1.2). I tried to deploy the application on weblogic server (at the beginning with JAVA 7) and I received the exception:

```
 weblogic.management.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type Manager with qualifiers @Default
     [java]   at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject protected (here is the package path) package.Manager
     [java]   at package.Manager(Session.java:0)
     [java]   Possible dependencies:
     [java]   - Managed Bean [class package.Manager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
     [java]   - Managed Bean [class package.Manager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
     [java] :org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException:WELD-001409: Ambiguous dependencies for type Manager with qualifiers @Default
     [java]   at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject protected package.Manager
     [java]   at package.Manager(Session.java:0)
     [java]   Possible dependencies:
     [java]   - Managed Bean [package.Manager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
     [java]   - Managed Bean [package.Manager] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
```

I would like to add that during deploying on the "old" weblogic version everything is on.

After upgrade java to 1.8 during deploying I receive exception like below:

```
weblogic.management.DeploymentException: CDI deployment failure:Exception List with 2 exceptions:
     [java] Exception 0 :
     [java] org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type ManagerAdapter with qualifiers @Default
     [java]   at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject protected package.ManagerAdapter
     [java]   at package.ManagerAdapter(ProjectManagerBase.java:0)
     [java]
     [java]     at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:359)
     [java]     at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:281)
     [java]     at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
     [java]     at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:155)
     [java]     at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
     [java]     at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBeans(Validator.java:504)
     [java]     at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateDeployment(Validator.java:479)
     [java]     at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldStartup.validateBeans(WeldStartup.java:446)
     [java]     at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.validateBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:90)
     [java]     at com.oracle.injection.provider.weld.WeldInjectionContainer.start(WeldInjectionContainer.java:150)
     [java]     at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.initCdi(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:84)
     [java]     at com.oracle.injection.integration.CDIAppDeploymentExtension.activate(CDIAppDeploymentExtension.java:43)
     [java]     at weblogic.application.internal.flow.AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.activate(AppDeploymentExtensionFlow.java:39)
     [java]     at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:752)
     [java]     at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:45)
     [java]     at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:262)
     [java]     at weblogic.application.internal.EarDeployment.activate(EarDeployment.java:66)
     [java]     at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165)
     [java]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:90)
     [java]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:631)
     [java]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:171)
     [java]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:121)
     [java]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:348)
     [java]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:907)
     [java]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1468)
     [java]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:459)
     [java]     at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:181)
     [java]     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:217)
     [java]     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:14)
     [java]     at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:69)
     [java]     at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:670)
     [java]     at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager._runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:352)
     [java]     at weblogic.invocation.ComponentInvocationContextManager.runAs(ComponentInvocationContextManager.java:337)
     [java]     at weblogic.work.LivePartitionUtility.doRunWorkUnderContext(LivePartitionUtility.java:57)
     [java]     at weblogic.work.PartitionUtility.runWorkUnderContext(PartitionUtility.java:41)
     [java]     at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.runWorkUnderContext(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:644)
     [java]     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:415)
     [java]     at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:355)
```

Do you have any ideas what can be a problem or where should I dig deeper ?

Thank's for all

Comment: Knowing what version of Weld was used in the previous and newer version would also be neat, then you could look into Weld release notes and try and spot possible breaking changes. Then you could show us the actual impl bean classes and injection points. All your exceptions are saying right now is - "hey, you got two bean eligible for this one IP" and "hey, you got no bean for that one".  Last but not least, what is your deployment structure (single war, multiple war, ear,..); something might have changed in the server in how they handle bean visibility across complex deployment maybe?

Comment: Deployment structure: a lot of wars combined into the ear.
BTW I will try to find version of Weld before changes, and look into the release notes

Answer (score 1):

You need to see the version for which your was developed forexample if it was for JavaEE 6, and now you are running it with JavaEE 7 then few things are different in JavaEE 7. For example It handles managed bean scopes differently. like the @ViewScoped annotation is not used in the Java EE 7 anymore (there is a new @FlowScoped). You can adjust log level to finest and get into details to understand what has happened.